# Adding rows that share a foreign key ID from the same table *in a new row*

Tags: mysql, join, foreign-key

My goal is as follows (simplified):

1. find the newest record from table `events`
2. use a FK `events_meta_id` to find all records from that same table (`events`) that have the same value in that field, if they exist

But, I'd like the subsequent records to appear as different rows, not as a part of the same row (like it does with INNER JOIN)

**Schemas**

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `events_meta_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tickets_quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `events_meta_id` (`events_meta_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `events_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`events_meta_id`) REFERENCES `events` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `events_meta` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `artist` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**My query is as follows:**

```sql
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM events
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1
) latest_events
INNER JOIN events
ON latest_events.events_meta_id = events.events_meta_id
```

**`events_meta` contents**

```
| id |   artist   |
|----|------------|
|  1 | Joe Cocker |
|  2 | BB King    |
|  3 | Nirvana    |
```

**`events` contents**

```
  id | events_meta_id | tickets_quantity 
 ----|----------------|------------------ 
   1 |              1 |               10 
   2 |              2 |               20 
   3 |              3 |               30 
   4 |              1 |                5
```

The resultset right now is this:

```
| id | events_meta_id | tickets_quantity | id | events_meta_id | tickets_quantity |
|----|----------------|------------------|----|----------------|------------------|
|  4 |              1 |                5 |  1 |              1 |               10 |
|  4 |              1 |                5 |  4 |              1 |                5 |
```

But I want this:

```
| id | events_meta_id | tickets_quantity |
|----|----------------|------------------|
|  4 |              1 |                5 |
|  1 |              1 |               10 |
```

Any ideas how?

Comment: Replace `SELECT * FROM` with `SELECT events.* FROM`

Comment: @Akina that fixed it, thanks a bunch (so simple)